# How to insert values in already created SQLite file in Android Studio?

Tags: sql, sqlite, android-studio

I am using Ionic 5 for app development. within Ionic framework, I have created SQLite database using [Ionic SQLite Plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/sqlite) where I am saving my app logs.
Further when building the app through Android Studio , I want to insert the crash logs which I can only access via Android Studio into the same Database file which is already created in my `File explorer > data > data > app_package_file > database` file .

To do this I have tried to create a SQLite database with same database name and same table name in Android Studio using this [documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite).
to add values into the database file I have added the below sort of code in Android Studio.

```js
val values = ContentValues().apply {
    put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_TITLE, date)
    put(FeedEntry.COLUMN_NAME_SUBTITLE, 'logs_data')
}
```

With this approach ,the existing database file do got updated , but when I download the database file from file explorer, I get only a blank file, to which I assume that my newly created SQLite db file has overriden the old one.

I know, my approach was not correct, but Is there any other way to achieve this requirement .

PS- This is my first question on SO, If anyone feel any improvement in the Question , please suggest an edit.

Thanks in advance ,for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of calling contentvalues() , and calling put function for each and every INSERT.
You can just use
`db.execSQL("INSERT INTO tablename VALUES('x','y','z')`.
into your MainActivity.java.

Comment: Hi @Sandesh  , thanks for the reply, where can I put this code in my MainActivity.java ??

Comment: You can add these line, below your function call of getwritableDatabase(). and don't forget to assign this function to a variable,  ex. SQLiteDatabase db= Your_helperfunction.getwritableDatabase ().  and then use this db in db.execSQL() .